# Python PANDAS - Manejo de columnas en dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

alguien sabe como añadir datos a una columna de pandas de modo que pueda iterar sobre ella y agregar más datos?

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["Netblocks"])
for NB in NBs.read().split():
    route = str(NB)
    df.append([{"Netblocks":route}])
print(df)
```

Comment: Si sabemos, pero sin ver tu `dataframe` ni tu código es imposible dar una respuesta concreta. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código que tienes hasta ahora (Como texto, no como imagen), algunas filas de tu `dataframe` y un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener al final de la ejecución. También agrega los errores o problemas que te impiden realizarlo.

Comment: Gracias ya está hecha la edición.

Comment: Ya probaste el `.loc` o el `.append`??

Comment: Loc? para qué? append si y "deprecated"

Comment: Aún no es claro lo que deseas lograr, ¿Para qué crear un `dataframe` vacío? Es mejor crear una lista o un diccionario con lo que contenga `NBs` y luego crear el `dataframe`. La función que reemplaza `append` es `concat` pero concatenar en cada iteración no es eficiente ya que consume muchos recursos, por lo que aún cuando desees agregar filas a un `dataframe` existente en lugar de uno vacío, lo mejor es crear una lista o diccionario. luego crear un `dataframe` con esos datos y en caso de que el primer `dataframe` ya tenga datos utilizar `concat` de otra forma bastaría con crearlo

Comment: Podrías hacer un script de ejemplo?

Comment: Ojalá se pudieran insertar `gif` en los comentarios, pero si has visto DragonBall: [El nivel de flojera está por encima de 9000!](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memes-pedia/images/b/b5/Its_over_9000.gif/revision/latest?cb=20160321005508&path-prefix=es) hahaha. Ya cree la respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Agregar filas a un `dataframe` en un ciclo no es conveniente ya que consume muchos recursos, la mejor forma de hacerlo es crear un iterable, puede ser una lista, tupla o diccionario con los datos que deseamos agregar al `dataframe`.

En tu pregunta no se entiende bien lo que deseas hacer, así que cubriré dos escenarios:

1. Agregar filas a un `dataframe` vacío.
2. Agregar filas a un `dataframe` que ya tiene datos.

### Escenario 1

Si deseas agregar filas a un `dataframe` vacío, lo mejor es primero generar los datos y al final crear el `dataframe`

Por ejemplo:

```
# Generamos una lista con los datos
# esto simula lo que obtienes en NBs
lista = []
for NB in range(5):
    lista.append(str(NB))

# Creamos el dataframe con los datos
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns = ['Netblocks'])
```

En este caso utilizamos una lista para agrupar los datos y al final creamos el `dataframe`

### Escenario 2

Si ya tienes un `dataframe` con datos y deseas agregar filas a este, de igual forma no es recomendable ir adjuntando fila por fila ya que consumirías muchos recursos. Lo mejor es crear un iterable que almacene todas las filas que desees adjuntar y luego concatenarlas a los datos existentes

Por ejemplo:

```
# Creamos una nueva lista para agregar más filas
nueva_lista = []
for NL in range(10, 20, 2):
    nueva_lista.append(str(NL))

# Creamos un nuevo dataframe con los nuevos datos
df2 = pd.DataFrame(nueva_lista, columns = ['Netblocks'])

# Concatenamos df1 y df2
df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index = True)
```

Ejemplo completo cubriendo ambos escenarios:

```
import pandas as pd

# Generamos una lista con los datos
# esto simula lo que obtienes en NBs
lista = []
for NB in range(5):
    lista.append(str(NB))

# Creamos el dataframe con los datos
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns = ['Netblocks'])

print('Primer dataframe')
print(df1)

# Creamos una nueva lista para agregar más filas
nueva_lista = []
for NL in range(10, 20, 2):
    nueva_lista.append(str(NL))
    
# Creamos un nuevo dataframe con los nuevos datos
df2 = pd.DataFrame(nueva_lista, columns = ['Netblocks'])

print('Segundo dataframe')
print(df2)

# Concatenamos df1 y df2
df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index = True)

print('Concatenados en df1')
print(df1)
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
Primer dataframe
  Netblocks
0         0
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
Segundo dataframe
  Netblocks
0        10
1        12
2        14
3        16
4        18
Concatenados en df1
  Netblocks
0         0
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
5        10
6        12
7        14
8        16
9        18
```